# NetSuite PDF file from Sales Order cannot be printed

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, netsuite

I have the following error popping up after clicking on the print function in one of the invoices.

**The template cannot be printed due to the following errors:**

**Error on line 242, column 51 in template. Detail... For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar): ==> record.duedate?string [in template "template" at line 242, column 53] ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${record.duedate?string("dd MMM yyyy")} [in template "template" at line 242, column 51] ----**

**Error on line 285, column 73 in template. Detail... For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar): ==> record.duedate?string [in template "template" at line 285, column 75] ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${record.duedate?string("dd MMM yyyy")} [in template "template" at line 285, column 73] ---- Please contact your administrator.**

Can someone explain the error and also explaining the way to access the script to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is in the Advanced HTML/PDF template associated with the form you are trying to print. `${record.duedate?string("dd MMM yyyy")}`  should be `${record.duedate?string["dd MMM yyyy"]}`

A couple more notes on formatting dates are available here: [How do I change the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242661/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy/68278579#68278579)

Answer (score 0):

I would concur with the other answer here about formatting it with brackets rather than parentheses—`string["dd MMM yyyy"]`. The language being used is FreeMarker, and the help documentation about date conversion can be found [here](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html).

Assuming you have NetSuite admin access, you can probably locate the PDF file by navigating to Customization > Forms > Advanced PDF/HTML Templates. From there, you can pinpoint which file is showing that error. Then just enable the "Source Code" switch and repair the line causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is resolved. And thank you for the clarification of the Markup Language documentation.

little problem occurs in the same line of code.

When I leave the field "record.duedate" empty I get following error:
**left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar): ==> record.duedate?string [in template "template" at line 285, column 75] ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${record.duedate?string["dd MMM yyyy"]} [in template "template" at line 285, column 73]]

How can I resolve without duedate?